# How to raise `Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'xxx'`?

Tags: typescript

[image]

There is a project that have lots of error like:

```
<Component doesNotExistValue="value" />
```

`Vscode` can report this error but typescript still compile this file successful, so somebody would ignore the error and commit it.

That will waste time if I check all files before commit so I want to raise this error when development for force fix all error.

Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: By mentioning `Vscode` reports did you mean eslint?

Comment: Could you please attach a picture for that error?

Comment: Please show the code of Component.

Comment: @RyanLe Add the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated images shows that you are adding a prop which is not expected to the component - this should show if you have ESLint / TS setup on vscode.

Comment: Yes, the error just shown on vscode. I want typescript could report it too.

Comment: Now typescript can compile successful so I can ignore the error.

Comment: TS shows the minimum props required in an interface, so if there are more than are provided it will allow them to pass through. Its a design of the language - if you want to stop any more than are explicitly provided i would expect other issues. I.e. i doubt you can get what you need.